# Ajax Request gives "uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input "

Tags: html, ajax, request

I have a problem with my Ajax Request I want to send to a specific page. I know that I can't just send Ajax requests to different pages because of the cross-domain problem. So I have chosen the jsonp method to do that.

My code is:

```
exs = function(url){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonp: "callback",
url: "http://example/api.php?callback=?",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response); 
    }
});
}
```

So what this returns is the following:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Does anyone know what's the problem?

I have checked the page of the API I'm sending the request, there I see just plain HTML.
And I want to save that HTML output to a variable.

I haven't found a solution yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can't just send Ajax requests to different pages because of the cross-domain problem. So I have chosen the jsonp method to do that.

If you want to use JSONP then the server has to provide a JSONP response, not an HTML response.

You can't bypass the same origin policy without either the cooperation of the server or the use of a proxy.

---

If you were using JSONP, then you should specify `dataType: "jsonp"` not `dataType: "json"` and you should generally avoid specifying the name of the function using `jsonp: "callback"` in favour of letting jQuery generate it from the success argument.

Comment: Sorry, the "dataType:"json"" was a typo from my side